# Is it possible to transfer an application bought under one Apple ID to another Apple ID?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

**How to see apps from different accounts**

Is it possible to see apps you got from a different account? I signed off one of my accounts where I had a paid app but I deleted it! The thing is, I forgot the password, so I have another account. The problem is that now I can't get back that app without paying again... U-U I don't mind so much about paying once more, but still, it's a bit frustrating! Help?!?

For those who find this unclear, I'll try my best to make it as clear as possible.
I have two accounts, one French account and the other Canadian
On my french account, I brought minecraft. 
I signed off the french account, but made the unfortunate mistake of forgetting the password and switched to my Canadian account.
Since I was trying to make space for another app, thinking I would be able to get minecraft back, I deleted the app.
In the end, my iPad kept saying I had no space left, therefore not able to get minecraft back. I am still on my Canadian account, wishing to see the apps on my french account to try to get minecraft back for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All applications downloaded by one Apple ID (free or not) and non-transferrable. iTunes support will tell you the same. There is nothing that can be done outside of retrieving/ resetting your password to the original Apple ID associated with the purchase. Then you can download the application again. Contact iTunes support to reset your Apple ID password.